# Retain YAML data when converting markdown to html with pandoc

Tags: yaml, pandoc

Is it possible to retain the `yaml` header in a markdown file when converting to `html` using `pandoc`?

Or, even better, convert the `yaml` to `json` and keep it in the converted file.

E.g.,

```
---
title: My Title
subtitle: My Subtitle
...

# Pandoc

We Love pandoc
```

To:

```
---
title: My Title
subtitle: My Subtitle
...

<h1>Pandoc</h1>

<p>We Love pandoc</p>
```

Or something like:

```
{title: "My Title", subtitle: "My Subtitle"}

<h1>Pandoc</h1>

<p>We Love pandoc</p>
```

**Update**

So, I guess I'll use templates and do something like this:

```
{title: $title$, subtitle:$subtitle$}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not out of the box as HTML doesn't have the concept of a YAML or JSON block (without javascript). You can customise your output with templates:

> [Templates](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demo/example9/templates.html)
>
> To see the default template that is used, just type
>
> ```
> pandoc -D FORMAT
> ```
>
> A custom template can be specified using the `--template` option. You
>   can also override the system default templates for a given output
>   format `FORMAT` by putting a file `templates/default.FORMAT` in the user
>   data directory (see `--data-dir`

So you can create a custom template that deals with values in the [YAML metadata block](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demo/example9/pandocs-markdown.html#yaml-metadata-block) as you see fit.

> [Examples 5.11 YAML metadata block](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demo/example19/YAML-metadata-block.html)
>
> Template variables will be set automatically from the metadata. Thus,
>   for example, in writing HTML, the variable `abstract` will be set to the
>   HTML equivalent of the markdown in the `abstract` field: